# How to Remove Launcher Off of Whisker Menu

Tags: ubuntu, xubuntu

## Story:

I had Clion downloaded from source onto my computer sometime back. Now I technically don't use C/C++ anymore, so I deleted the source folder. But the launcher is still in the Whisker Menu:

[image: Whisker Menu]

Now it's a icon-less, empty launcher.

## Question:

*How can I get rid of this redundant launcher?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you see clion in `~/.local/share/applications`? If you can, you need to erase the folder or file.

Answer (score 2):

XFCE4 launchers appearing in Whisker Menu can be gotten rid of in two ways.
If you *never* want to see a launcher again, choose the **remove file option**. However if you just want it to not show up but *consider seeing it again in the future*, choose the **hide launcher option**.

1. Remove the configuration file which is read by Whisker Menu in every
   menu opening (`xfce4-popup-whiskermenu`).
   The configuration file is a plain/text file with a `.desktop` extension usually.

There are two possible locations to delete such files from (that I know of):

Non- Linux Mint user: `~/.local/share/applications`

Linux Mint user: `/usr/share/applications`

2. Hide the launcher from the Whisker Menu using the **Application Finder**
   (`xfce4-appfinder`).
   To do this, search for the launcher using Application Finder, use right-click on the resulting menu item and choose the `Hide` option.
   This is achieved by appending a `Hidden=true` line to the launcher's
   configuration file.
   Therefore, to unhide a launcher, simply remove said line from the configuration file.

Note: hiding a launcher simply means it won't show up in the Whisker Menu,
whereas removing the launcher is done by removing a file.

Answer (score 0):

This may be an old posted question but I thought I should chime in anyway since I had the same problem.

However, none of these suggestions worked but I found on the internet a very smart person who knew of a program called *Alacarte* (easy GNOME menu editing). I installed it using the software manager and I'm thrilled it's still available because it used to be installed by default but isn't now and is not a well known program.

I'm glad it It's still available via software manager and it's so easy to use: just click on to highlight the program entry you want to get rid of and click delete on the right and it's done. Maybe this will help if these other suggestions don't work for you

Comment: Welcome to the site and thank you for your contribution. If you have a link available that points to (documentation of) the program, please consider editing your post to include it, so that others may find it more easily.