# How to remove orphan launcher in Whisker Menu?

Tags: linux-mint, xfce, menu, launcher

I'm using Linux Mint 18.3 (Xfce 4.12) and have a launcher that seemingly can't be removed (any way I can think of; highlighted in the image below):

[image: The orphan launcher in Whisker Menu]

After updating a VPN client, there are two entries. One is correct and working (with proper icon, working directory and command) while the other points to a non-existent directory (and so fails to launch). MenuLibre editor shows only one launcher entry (the working one), as do `~/.config/menus/xfce-applications.menu` and `/usr/share/applications` (per [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/388954/how-to-remove-launcher-off-of-whisker-menu)).

Editing either launcher icon via context-menu (right-click) doesn't give the option to hide it, either. Are there other ways to get rid of this launcher entry?

Answer (score 0):

Right click on Menu button, click on Edit Applications: shows Menu libre page. Find your orphan from the application list at left. Click it. Hit the minus (-) button at the bottom of the form and reboot. The orphan should have disappeared.

Took me a long while to find that!

Comment: 4 years on, I don't recall exactly what I saw in the MenuLibre editor, but this was already attempted, as mentioned in the question (the orphaned launcher wasn't in the menu editor).